# how to insert a column to a finished table in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm using html create a table like this:

```
<h1>SEAFOOD<br><span>w. White Rice</span></h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>72.</td>
                        <td>Shrimp Lo Mein</td>
                        <td>6.75</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>73.</td>
                        <td>Burry Shrimp</td>
                        <td>9.25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>74.</td>
                        <td>Shrimp w. Mixed Vegetable</td>
                        <td>9.25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>75.</td>
                        <td>Shrimp w. Mushroon</td>
                        <td>9.25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>76.</td>
                        <td>Shrimp w. Garlic Shuce</td>
                        <td>9.25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>77.</td>
                        <td>Szechuan Shrimp</td>
                        <td>9.25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>78.</td>
                        <td>Coconut Shrimp</td>
                        <td>11.99</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

and I figured out that I need one more dish between shrimp lo mein and burry shrimp

since I don't want to reenter the whole dish number to my table, is there any faster way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can either update all the next rows in the tables, or let the browser do it for you with css.
check out this jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/Xkj6u/1/

counting in CSS3 can be done using counter-increment.
so, for example:

```
body { counter-reset: numList; } //resetting the counter
span.counter::after {
      counter-increment: numList; //increment
      content: counter(numList) "."; //write to content
}
```

Will cause each counter span (span with `class=counter`) to be numbered.

The browser will keep this rule, even when the span's location changes, or when other spans are dynamically added in between.

you can do the same with `<td>`'s

```
table{counter-reset: numList} //reset counter when a table begins
tr td:first-child::before { //first-child = the first TD in the TR
      counter-increment: numList; //increment
      content: counter(numList) "."; //write to content
}
```

forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/9LZNd/

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

Answer (score 0):

The numbers appear to be part of the content – they will presumably be used to refer to the dishes when ordering –, so they are best included in the HTML markup, rather than added with CSS or JavaScript.

Depending on the technology used to create and edit the pages, there might be handy tools for doing the numbering for you. You could then maintain a table without numbers somewhere, and the tool (e.g., PHP code) would generate a HTML `table` element, with numbers inserted.